# How do I protect my uploads?

Tags: uploads, attachments, content-restriction, privacy

If I type in url for some of my attachments: `/wp-content/uploads/20xx/` I can easily download everything even if I'm not logged in which is not what I want to happen.

How can I redirect users to login page if they try to view my attachments directly?